# PHP - Square Brackets Before Functions

Tags: arrays, function, random

I use `array_rand` function  to get random arrays value.
after searching i found this code :

```
$random = $arList[array_rand($arList)];
```

My questions: Why use Square brackets before `array_rand` function? and when should we use it in our code?

```
[array_rand($arList)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets don't have anything to with the `array_rand()` function. The code

`$random = $arList[array_rand($arList)];`

can be rewritten as

`$randomIndex = array_rand($arList);
$random = $arList[$randomIndex];`

The code basically gets a random index and passes the value of that index to the `$random` variable. The square brackets are PHP array syntax to represent a particular index in the array.

The first value of `$arList` would be `$arList[0]` (it starts counting from 0). The second would be `$arList[1]` and so on. So, as I mentioned before, `array_rand` doesn't have anything to do with the square brackets.

You can find out more about arrays in PHP [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).